# Can the idea of "imperfect" categorical imperatives be used without 'duty'?

Tags: terminology, metaethics, categorical-imperative

Can the idea of "imperfect" categorical imperatives be used without 'duty'? So that e.g. I can say that something has an intrinsic *value*, and not hypothetically, but it is always valuable, even-though we rationally can on occasion sacrifice that value to something more valuable.

If not, is there a term of art for values of that sort?